# Trouble with fetch request in FireFox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, firefox, fetch

We've got this rather large'ish and old'ish asp web application, that started to behave poorly because of (as i understand) XHR requests in beforeunload event handler. There is quite a logic tied to this, so i cannot just throw it away.
The code in beforeunload was like this:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    $.ajax('/site/$hdr/unload', { async: true, cache: false });
});
```

and in server side something like this:

```
private class HttpModule : IHttpModule
{
  private static void PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var context = HttpContext.Current;
    var path = context.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
    if (path.StartsWith("~/$hdr/unload")) 
    {
       //do things
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to use the fetch api instead of synchronous ajax request used before. In chrome everything works fine, but FireFox 89.0 behaves strangely.
Code in beforeunload is like this:

```
      let i;
      let data = new Headers();
      if (window.FMS && window.FMS.HttpHeaders) {
          for (i in window.FMS.HttpHeaders) {
              if (FMS.HttpHeaders.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                  data.append('X-FMS-' + i, FMS.HttpHeaders[i]);
              }
          }
      }
             
      fetch(FMS.UnloadUrl +  '?_=' + jQuery.now(), {
          method: 'GET',
          keepalive: true,
          cache: 'no-cache',
          headers: data }
      ).then(response => response.ok)
      .then(IsOk => console.debug(IsOk.toString()))
      .catch((error) => {console.error('Error:', error)});
```

If my understanding is correct - the server side now have to receive OPTIONS preflight request first? I never receive this. Sometimes i receive the GET request, but usually in the FireFox console i can see TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource error or notification that the XHR request has been blocked by DevTools.

Comment: For the Ajax part you use the native `fetch` api, but for the actual time you use jQuery? o.O

Comment: I was given to 'take a look' at this, it's almost first time i touch web app. So it's highly likely  i did something stupid here :)